# Passing managedObjectContext to UITabBarController issues

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitabbarcontroller

I'm making a Core Data based iPhone application which stores some data.

It has a `UITabBarController` as the root view controller (`RootViewController`). The tab bar controller is given two view controllers by the application delegate - the first one being an instance of `UIViewController` which represents the title screen of the app and the second one being a `UITableViewController` which is used to display the data.

This is my first iPhone application using Core Data. I've read that the proper way of building this kind of apps is to create and initialize the `managedObjectModel`, `managedObjectContext` and `persistentStoreCoordinator` objects in the application delegate and then pass the `managedObjectContext` to the child view controllers by reference. This is how I did it.

However, I didn't manage to pass the `managedObjectContext` object into the tab bar controller which I initialize in my application delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [window addSubview:rootViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [rootViewController release];
    return YES;
}
```

Even though the tab bar is displayed properly and loads the title screen view controller, its `managedObjectContext` remains nil. I wasn't able to figure out what am I doing wrong. I also tried to pass the `RootViewController` a string by adding a new retained property to it.

My `RootViewController.h` reads as it follows:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITabBarController {
@private 
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

My RootViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectContext);

ObiadViewController *obiadVC = [[ObiadViewController alloc] init];
ObiadListNavController *obiadListVC = [[ObiadListNavController alloc] init];

obiadVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
obiadListVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

NSArray *vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obiadVC, obiadListVC, nil];

self.viewControllers = vcs;

[obiadVC release];
[obiadListVC release];
```

}

I also checked that the `managedObjectContext` is not nil in the application delegate, just before it gets passed to the `RootViewController` instance. It's like all `RootViewController`'s ivars get reset. It happens only at this point. When I pass a string from the table view controller to the detail view controller later on, everything is just fine.

I hope I made myself clear. I'm feeling pretty clueless at the moment.

Comment: What does NSLog(@"%@", self.managedObjectContext); output in your TabBarController.m? IF it's nil, you're actually putting your managedObjectContext to nil. Shouldn't `obiadVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;` be `obiadVC.managedObjectContext = self.delegate.managedObjectContext;` ?

Comment: isn’t `RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil]` instead of a simple alloc/init?;

Answer (score 2):

[UITabBarController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) clearly states that UITabBarController isn't supposed to be subclassed:

> This class is not intended for subclassing.

In this case you could instantiate your UITabBarController and add view controllers to it in your App Delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    firstViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    secondViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSArray *vcs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = vcs;

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [firstViewController release];
    [secondViewController release];

    return YES;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would you do that with storyboard? Because you don't have access to your view controllers programatically, or rather, there is no need to.